# Where are "higlights, shadows, whites and blacks" in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I'm experimenting with doing all my editing in Photoshop instead of Lightroom. Does Photoshop have these filters/sliders that Lightroom has to change the levels on Highlights, Shadows, Whites and Blacks:

[image: higlights, shadows, whites and blacks]

I find myself missing them very often and I can't find them in Photoshop.

Comment: Have you tried the curves tool?  Most adjustments, including those you ask about, have corresponding curve adjustments you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my copy of Photoshop CC 2018 these are located under `Filter -> Camera Raw Filter`:
[image: Filter menu with Camera Raw Filter highlighted]

There you have the shadow, highlights, blacks and whites in the lower right:
[image: Camera Raw Filter window]